# listening for changes in network state

Tags: networking, ip

I have a panel label displaying the external IP. I get this through:

```
wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain
```

I want this label to be sensitive to network changes. For example, a VPN up or down, or a network fails, but:

I want to avoid hitting `ipecho.net` every second or ten, so I'm looking for another way of doing it.

Comment: On linux you do that via route netlink sockets. A shell interface to it is via [`ip monitor link`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-monitor.8.html)

Comment: And of course, unless you're behind a NAT, `ip route get 8.8.8.8` will get your "external" ipv4 address as the source. And you would better monitor route rather than link changes with `ip monitor`

Comment: @pizdelect `ip monitor` is interesting. `ip route get 8.8.8.8` returns the LAN gateway. What am I missing?

Comment: I think it may not work if with `ip monitor` You are not managing the connections from that device. The link state and the routes and so on are not changing for Your device. So You need to pull something or configure Your gateway to inform You if possible.

Comment: `ip route get 8.8.8.8` (or any well known network or host instead of 8.8.8.8) will tell you something like `... src x.x.x.x` which is the address of your machine. If you're behind a NAT, that will be some rfc1918 "private" address like 192.168.0.17 or 10.0.0.13. If you're running the NAT yourself (eg you're using a router), you should run the script on the router. It makes little sense to monitor the link or routes on a machine hidden behind a NAT  -- as they don't affect the address seen by websites and other people on the internet.

Comment: @pizdelect Ah. That's the thing then. My router is supplied by my ISP.  I could set up my own router, I suppose. I might enjoy that but it's the kind of thing where I'd really need to know what I'm doing, isn't that right? Not a safe thing to deploy on a whim and a tinker?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic it uses `ip  monitor` to detect "Net down".

Comment: Given the similarity in names, please make it apparent (in an edit to the question) whether you are or are not the author of that software. Thank you! It would be *even better* if you imported the pertinent portions of the link so that this is not flagged as a "link-only" answer in the future.